# Filling model with 2 foreign keys on Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views

Good evening fellows and happy workers day. I have this task, that is, filling an intermediate model with two foreign keys from two other models.

```
Class A:
    string_attr = models.CharField()
    string_attr_2 = models.CharField()

Class B:
    string_attr_x = models.CharField()
    string_attr_y = models.CharField()

Class C:
    date_attr = models.DateField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

The task is given a object from Model A, create as many objects that the table from class B has on model C. That is, given that class B has 4 objects and with the object X from class A, create 4 objects on table C.

Class A is a Pacients Model and class B is a Vital Signs and class C is PacientVitalSign model, for any given Pacient, I want to show a Formset or anything like it, with every vital sign to set on the PacientVitalSign model.

I don't know if the point is clear enough, English is not my mother language. I've look django-extra-views to achieve this task but I haven't hit the right key.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you should be using M2M models. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: @stupidbodo no I dont... my idea is something like this... or sort of https://github.com/offmessage/django-crispy-extensions/blob/master/docs/manytomany-intermediate.rst

Comment: it's best that you look at it carefully. It's actually a ManytoMany model. Look for the keyword "through" that is where the name of the intermediate model comes from